# Darn - that slash command didn't work (error message: `404_client_error`)

Tags: slack, pubnub, slack-commands

I am attempting to call a URI with my Slack `slash command` but I get the error:

```
https://pubsub.pubnub.com/v1/blocks/sub-key/sub-c-redacted/mypath

Darn - that slash command didn't work (error message: `404_client_error`). Manage the command at Freshdesk Field Update.
```

The URI I am trying to call works when I `curl` it (`POST` and `GET`) or just paste it in my browser address.

So I tried a `webhook.site` URI and it worked fine in the same `slash command`

```
https://webhook.site/404279dd-369b-4224-8672-94fa5c0a826c
```

And this works just fine. Unsure of why the PubNub URI is failing.

Comment: I would suggest to test your endpoint with a tool like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) instead. For testing you want to emulate a HTTP POST request from Slack to your endpoint. It should look like [this](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands#app_command_handling). Also, are you receiving anything on your endpoint from Slack? What does your log say?

Comment: I am curl'ing my endpoint as GET and POST with success. It is accessible from anywhere but Slack command. My slack command is returning the error that I posted in my question: `Darn - that slash command didn't work (error message: `404_client_error`)`. And I know it is not reaching my endpoint at all because there is an output console that shows no activity as it does when I curl.

Comment: I think you may have more luck with this kind of issue at the Slack support. You can open a new ticket through your Slack workspace. They are pretty quick in responding.

Comment: I got past the 404 issue and I am hitting my endpoint now. But I am unsure why it wasn't working. I just created a new PubNub account and created a new Function to hit and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure of why the error was occurring but seemed to have something to do with my PubNub Admin Dashboard account. I deleted it and created a new one and it started working with the new function in a new key set in a new account.

If anyone knows actual root cause (perhaps more generic issue than just PubNub account), please provide and I will review and approve as answer if I can verify it.

But for now, my answer is, try creating a new PubNub account.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add template mapping in api gate way. In the integration section you can add it. So that the request from slack will properly map to json. 
Find examples here : [here](https://medium.com/@cu_tech/create-a-slack-slash-command-with-aws-lambda-83fb172f9a74) and [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=673012&tstart=0#673012).

Comment: Ah, ok. I'll have to revisit my project and check that out.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error, when I was using localhost as the url but after I deployed the server, where slack sends the post request to now and got the url from there. the error is gone.